# How to resolve CMake Error: Could not find a package configuration file provided by "boost_python3"

Tags: python, boost, cmake, build

I tried to install the lanelet2 library according to the github installation guide at https://github.com/fzi-forschungszentrum-informatik/Lanelet2.

When I perform catkin build I get the following error:

```
Errors     << lanelet2_python:cmake /home/student/catkin_ws/logs/lanelet2_python/build.cmake.000.log
CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake:117 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "boost_python3"
  (requested version 1.71.0) with any of the following names:

    boost_python3Config.cmake
    boost_python3-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "boost_python3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "boost_python3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "boost_python3" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
```

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04 with ROS noetic. The build is performed inside a venv with Python Version 3.8.10.

The command python is pointing to python3. I've also installed the following dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-rospack ros-noetic-catkin ros-noetic-mrt-cmake-modules
```

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-dev libeigen3-dev libgeographic-dev libpugixml-dev libpython3-dev libboost-python-dev python3-catkin-tools
```

Does someone have an idea how to resolve this error?

Comment: I'm having the same problem... did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

See neutrinoyu's comment at https://github.com/ethz-asl/kalibr/issues/368#issuecomment-651726289

> ```
> /kalibr/Schweizer-Messer/numpy_eigen/cmake/add_python_export_library.cmake:89
> change
> list(APPEND BOOST_COMPONENTS python3)
> to
> list(APPEND BOOST_COMPONENTS python)
> ```

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) and make sure to credit and cite material written by someone else.